# Border touch button :active applying but not firing event

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, touch

I am currently working on a [small] touch screen UI. I am running into an issue where the user can accidentally hit just on the edge of our buttons and have the active CSS trigger, but not the `touchend` event fire since the button wasn't actually pressed.

Here is a visual representation, the yellow box being a finger click and the button being in the active state, but not activating the event.

[image: sample picutre]

Here is the scss as well in-case it's relevant

```
.action-button {
  @extend .nav-button;
  height: 85%;
  border-radius: $border-radius;
  border: none;
  min-width: 85px;
  margin: {
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
  }
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-button {
  &.active {
    background-color: $active-button-background-color;
  }
  &:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
.nav-button:active {
  background-color: $active-button-background-color;
}
```

Here is a fiddle so you can play around with this as well https://jsfiddle.net/kaagu3dj/12/  [note you will need to be in a touch simulator mode]

So TL;DR, what is the best way to 'capture' this edge touch with a button?

Thanks!

Comment: As per your design there is no needs of border so you simply remove your border and whole the stuff working fine.. :)

Comment: I'll make an edit, but border == edge in this context. I am running into an issue where the user can touch the edge of these buttons and the `touchend` event isn't firing, but the `:active` css is applying

Comment: Can you please create fiddle? So i can update code there.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here is the  [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kaagu3dj/3/) You will need to put your browser in a touchscreen mode to minic the touch events. You can see the number go up when the event fires and if you position your touch on the edge of the button you can see the event doesn't trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*That's native behavior of touchend and touchstart event.
So you can do the same something like this.*

Remove your **:active** pseudo-class CSS, and add in script like below.

```
let count = 0;
$('.main').on('touchstart', function(event) {
  count++;
  $('#count').html(count);
  $('.main').css("background", "blue");
});
$('.main').on('touchend', function(event){
    $('.main').css("background", "#ddd");
});
```

Might be this will help you. also you get more idea from [***fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/kaagu3dj/14/)

Comment: Makes sense, I was working with focus / blur events, this is a lot more elegant